# How can I redirect a user if they are not authenticated using router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In Angular 2 how can I redirect a user if they are not authenticated using router version 2.0.0-rc.1

I'm looking to do this in my app.component where my routes are store.

I want to detect if the user is authenticated before it hits a pages component.
So I can then redirect them to the login.

I've tried **canActivate** which doesnt seem to work for my router version.

I'm looking for a solution for this version of the router:     **"@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1"**

OR

A solution for the latest version of the router. If one is provided can you show me how to update my router version using git bash with this solution.

**This is my current code:**

```
export class AppComponent implements CanActivate {
    authService: AuthService;
    userService: UserService;

    constructor(_authService: AuthService, _userService: UserService, private location: Location, private router: Router) {
        this.authService = _authService;
        this.userService = _userService;
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable < boolean > | boolean {

        //This doesnt get hit
        console.log("here");

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: John Papa has a pretty good example of using CanActivate/CanDeactivate here: https://github.com/johnpapa/event-view. Although, he is using RC4.

Comment: What's the git bash command to update my router node module? For rc4

Comment: Ideally I want to use my current router version

Comment: The 2.0.0 router is deprecated. Wouldn't you rather be on 3.0.0 since that is the latest version for Angular 2? (3.0.0-beta.2 may actually work)

Comment: Will it break a lot of my work?

Comment: Probably, yes, anything router related anyway. Which could effect a lot. I made the transition kicking and fighting, but it was worth it. :)

Comment: What's the git bash command to update my node module for the router

Comment: No idea, I am not a git bash user. Maybe someone else will chime in on that one.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Interceptor`:

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as _ from 'lodash'

import {MyApp} from './app/my-app';

class HttpInterceptor extends Http {

    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private _router: Router) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.request(url, options));
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.get(url,options));
    }

    post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {   
        return this.intercept(super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.delete(url, options));
    }

    getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }
        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers();
        }
        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return options;
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch((err, source) => {
            if (err.status  == 401 && !_.endsWith(err.url, 'api/auth/login')) {
                this._router.navigate(['/login']);
                return Observable.empty();
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        });

    }
}

bootstrap(MyApp, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
    provide(Http, {
        useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router) => new HttpInterceptor(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router]
    })
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to add to my app.component file where my routes are. I want to catch the route before it hits the pages component so I can redirect them to login page if they are not authenticated

Comment: I'm surprised this is the answer as it's about 4-5 times more code than solving the same issue in angular 1.

Comment: well you could override just the `get` method

Comment: When I try to inject router in interceptor using useFactory I get following exception
ARNING in ./~/@angular/Router/@angular/router.es5.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
node_modules\@angular\Router\@angular\router.es5.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
............

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        catchError(
          (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (this.router.url !== '/login' && err.status === 401) {
              this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
            return throwError(err);
          }
        )
      );
  }

}
```

And in app.module.ts

```
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
  multi: true,
},
```